# Http Post Request with Boundry Error Bad Request

Tags: c#, http-post

Hi I am trying to do Http Post request but getting error of bad request I think I am doing something wrong in request if any one can help me.

**This is the request**

```
     POST /uapi/faxes/@me/0003*210 HTTP/1.1
     HOST uapi.voipnow.com
     Content-Length:469
     Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=------------325343636
     ------------325343636-------- 
     Content-Disposition:form-data; name="files"; filename="/path/to/file/fax.txt"
     Content-Type;application/octet-stream

     This is my fax
     ------------325343636
     Content-Disposition:form-data; name="request";
     {
       "recipients":["7778888"]
     }
     ------------3253436360
```

**This is my code for this request**

```
        try
           {
             String Token = "mytoken";
            ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = new RemoteCertificateValidationCallback(delegate { return true; });
            HttpWebRequest httpWReq2 = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://domainname/uapi/faxes/@me/0014*100/?accessRequestToken=" + Token);

            ASCIIEncoding encoding2 = new ASCIIEncoding();
            string postData2 =
            "------------325343636" + Environment.NewLine +
            "Content-Disposition:form-data; name=\"files\";filename=\"/path/to/file/fax.txt\";" + Environment.NewLine +
            "Content-Type:application/octet-stream;" + Environment.NewLine +
            "This is my fax" + Environment.NewLine +
            "------------325343636" + Environment.NewLine +
            "Content-Disposition:form-data; name=\"request\";" + Environment.NewLine +
            "{" + Environment.NewLine +
            "\"recipients\":[\"111111\"];" + Environment.NewLine +
            "}" + Environment.NewLine +
            "------------325343636";

            byte[] data2 = encoding2.GetBytes(postData2);
            httpWReq2.Method = "POST";
            httpWReq2.ContentType = "multipart/form-data; boundary=------------325343636";
            httpWReq2.KeepAlive = true;
            httpWReq2.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1) AppleWebKit/537.17 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/24.0.1312.52 Safari/537.17";
            httpWReq2.ContentLength =data2.Length;
            httpWReq2.Host = "hostname";
            string result2 = "";

            Stream dataStream2 = httpWReq2.GetRequestStream();
            dataStream2.Write(data2, 0, data2.Length);
            dataStream2.Close();
            WebResponse response2 = httpWReq2.GetResponse();
            HttpWebResponse responce3 = (HttpWebResponse)httpWReq2.GetResponse();
            dataStream2 = response2.GetResponseStream();
            // Open the stream using a StreamReader for easy access.
            StreamReader reader2 = new StreamReader(dataStream2);
            // Read the content.
            string responseFromServer2 = reader2.ReadToEnd();
           }

            catch (Exception ex)
        {
            WebException ex2 = (WebException)ex;
            if (ex2.Status == WebExceptionStatus.ProtocolError)
            {
                WebResponse resp = ex2.Response;
                using (Stream respstream = resp.GetResponseStream())
                {
                    StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(respstream);
                    String finalerror = reader.ReadToEnd();
                }
            }

        }
```

**Error**

> Value supplied in recipients parameter is missing or invalid. The
>   parameter must reference any phone number

Comment: what server are you posting to? this is vendor-specific.

Comment: @DanielA.White ye sir,You are right,This is vendor specific. I want to know what is wrong with my PostData in my Request.

Comment: @DiskJunky I thought Content length should be same as PostData Length ,Am I wrong?

Comment: you should elaborate on what server you are posting to. its impossible to know what its exactly expecting.

Answer (score 0):

Oh I see a potential problem. It looks like you are sending up a JSON object instead a forms encoded value.

```
 ------------325343636
 Content-Disposition:form-data; name="request";
 recipients=7778888
 ------------3253436360
```

Try something along those lines.

Comment: So in my code change should be   
            "{" + Environment.NewLine +
            "recipients:111111" + Environment.NewLine +
            "}" + Environment.NewLine + I try this but still getting sam error

Comment: @Hiren i need an example request from the api

Answer (score 0):

Your boundaries don't match.

```
 POST /uapi/faxes/@me/0003*210 HTTP/1.1
 HOST uapi.voipnow.com
 Content-Length:469
 Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=------------325343636
 --------------325343636
 Content-Disposition:form-data; name="files"; filename="/path/to/file/fax.txt"
 Content-Type;application/octet-stream

 This is my fax
 --------------325343636
 Content-Disposition:form-data; name="request";
 {
   "recipients":["7778888"]
 }
 --------------325343636--
```

Your boundaries should be -- (two hyphens) + your boundary. The last boundary should follow the same formula with an addition -- (two hyphens) at the end.

In your example you had the closing boundary different and didn't have the extra two hyphens in the front of your boundaries.

To clarify a bit more, if you're boundary was "a boundary", it would look like so:

```
 POST /uapi/faxes/@me/0003*210 HTTP/1.1
 HOST uapi.voipnow.com
 Content-Length:469
 Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=a boundary
 --a boundary
 Content-Disposition:form-data; name="files"; filename="/path/to/file/fax.txt"
 Content-Type;application/octet-stream

 This is my fax
 --a boundary
 Content-Disposition:form-data; name="request";
 {
   "recipients":["7778888"]
 }
 --a boundary--
```